# ROS Jade on ubuntu 14.04 E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-openni-tracker

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning to work on parrot Jumping Sumo by using gesture control using ROS and Kinect. I have installed the all the required packages except openni_tracker. When i try the conmmand :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-openni-tracker
```

I get the following error:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-openni-tracker
```

Can someone please help me solve the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246738/ros-jade-on-ubuntu-14.04-e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-jade-openni-tracker/) by [sg_774](https://answers.ros.org/users/23284/sg_774/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [wiki/openni_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker) and [status_page/ros_jade_default.html?q=openni](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_jade_default.html?q=openni), that packages has not been released into Jade, so you cannot install it using `apt-get`.

The latest released version is for Hydro. You may be able to build the package from sources. The wiki page has the link to the github repository containing them.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0